# How to Assign value for unique values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

df:

```
Id     Products
100     Shoes
101     Shoes
102     Shoes
103     Chair
104     Chair
105     Chair
106     Chair
107     Chair
108     Clothes
109     Clothes
110     Clothes
```

df_Output:

```
Id     Products Value
100     Shoes    1
101     Shoes    1
102     Shoes    1
103     Chair    2
104     Chair    2
105     Chair    2
106     Chair    2
107     Chair    2
108     Clothes  3
109     Clothes  3
110     Clothes  3
```

I need to create a new column based on 'Products' column, which assigns each unique value for each distinct Products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `factorize`

```
df['Value']=df.Products.factorize()[0]+1
```

Output

```
df
     Id Products  Value
0   100    Shoes      1
1   101    Shoes      1
2   102    Shoes      1
3   103    Chair      2
4   104    Chair      2
5   105    Chair      2
6   106    Chair      2
7   107    Chair      2
8   108  Clothes      3
9   109  Clothes      3
10  110  Clothes      3
```